# How to properly create a JS class with asynchronously initiated properties?

Tags: node.js, class, asynchronous

I'm sorry for complicated explanation:

I want to a class instance to be initiated but in async/await way, because in constructor we are not allowed to use async/await. So I tought maybe I can call a static asynchronous method of that class which will initiate and return instance while populating class properties.

```
const ccxt = require('ccxt')
const Events = require('events')

class Exchange {
  constructor (platform, uid) {
    this.platform = platform
    this.uid = uid
    this.keys = {} // Should by asynchronously populated on class init
    this.exchange = null // Should pick a correct exchange platform
  }
  
  static async init (platform, uid) {
    this.instance = new Exchange(platform, uid)
    
    if (!this.keys || !this.keys[platform]) {
      await this.instance.fetchKeys(uid)
    }
    
    this.instance.setExchange(platform)
    
    return this.instance
  }
  
  async fetchKeys (uid) {
    // this.keys = database.findOne('settings', { user_id: uid })
    // FOLLOWING LINE IS TO SIMULATE A RESPONSE FROM DB
    this.keys = {
      binance: { key: 'apikey', secret: 'apisecret' },
      bybit: { key: 'apikey', secret: 'apisecret' },
      kukoin: { key: 'apikey', secret: 'apisecret' }
    }
  }
  
  setExchange (platform) {
    this.exchange = new ccxt[platform]({
      apiKey: this.keys[platform].key,
      secret: this.keys[platform].secret
    })
  }
}
```

Then I can get an instance of that class like this:

```
const binance = await Exchange.init('binance', 111)
const bybit = await Exchange.init('bybit', 111)
```

App is listening for WebSocket prices and emits a Server-Side-Events (SSE) so we can listen on them and fire a callback:

```
const onWsPriceEventCallback = async (event, bot) => {
  const { platform, symbol, price } = event

  if (bot.symbol === symbol && bot.platform_id === platform) {
    console.log(`Bot #${bot.id} - Platform requested: ${platform} - Platform received: ${Exchange.platform} - Price: ${price} ${symbol}`)
  }
}

// Here we listen for events
Events.on('price', (event) => onWsPriceEventCallback(event, bot))
```

###### Results I expect to get in console.log

```bash
Bot #1 - Platform requested: binance - Platform received: binance - Price: 28196.54 BTCUSDT
Bot #2 - Platform requested: bybit   - Platform received: bybit - Price: 28195.11 BTCUSDT
Bot #1 - Platform requested: binance - Platform received: binance - Price: 28196.97 BTCUSDT
```

###### Instead I get this in console.log

```bash
Bot #1 - Platform requested: binance - Platform received: binance - Price: 28196.54 BTCUSDT
Bot #2 - Platform requested: bybit   - Platform received: bybit - Price: 28195.11 BTCUSDT
Bot #1 - Platform requested: binance - Platform received: bybit - Price: 28196.97 BTCUSDT // WRONG
```

If requested platform is "binance", then it should receive "binance" and not the other one.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exhange.platform` is accessing a property on the class, there can only ever be one value.  It looks like it gets set to `binance` then `bybit` and then doesn't change at all.

I would suggest avoiding storing values with `this` context in the init method to cleanup the logic and then go from there.

For example:

```
  static async init (platform, uid) {
    const instance = new Exchange(platform, uid)
    
    if (!instance.keys || !instance.keys[platform]) {
      await instance.fetchKeys(uid)
    }
    
    instance.setExchange(platform)
    
    return instance
  }
```

This assumes you just need the async field initialized and do not need Exchange to be a singleton.

Comment: Yes exactly, I do not want it to be a singleton. I've updated the code but it still keeps receiving a platform from the one which is defined as last.

Comment: Where in your current code is `Exchange.platform` getting set?  In my suggestion it would never have any value, instead `binance.platform` and `bybit.platform` should be verified to be correct.

Comment: I think I managed to fix it, by adding a third param as an "exchange" for a `onWsPriceEventCallback(event, bot, exchange)`, which actually `exchange = new Exchange.init('binance', 'userid')`
Thank you for  your suggestion to avoid using `this` context